What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(L_n)^{\frac1n}$ about the LCM of this special double sequence?
As an intermediate step looking for the irrationality of the Catalan's constant, I need the value of this limit $$\rho=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(L_n)^{\frac1n}$$ where $L_n$ is the least common multiple of this integer double sequence containing $n(n+1)$ elements $$L_n=\text{LCM}\left(\left[\ (2j+1)\cdot k\ \right]_{j=1,k=1}^{\ \ n,\ \ \ 2j}\right)$$ Numerical tests up to $n=10^5$ give the value of $\rho\sim 14.4$  which it is conjectured to be equal to $e^{\small{\frac83}}$
Q: Is there a way to prove it? or
is it possible to find a closed form for this limit?
Any suggestion is appreciated ...

Yes, the limit is $e^{8/3}$. We compute the factorization of $L_n$ and apply the prime number theorem.
Put $L_n=\prod_{p\leqslant 2n+1}p^{a_p(n)}$ (here and below, $p$ runs over primes), so that
$$
a_p(n)=\max\{\nu_p(2j+1)+\nu_p(k) : 1\leqslant j\leqslant n, 1\leqslant k\leqslant 2j\},\tag{*}\label{expodef}
$$
where $\nu_p(m)$ denotes the greatest integer $k$ such that $p^k$ divides $m$.
If $p=2$ then $\nu_p(2j+1)=0$, thus $a_2(n)=\max\{\nu_2(k):1\leqslant k\leqslant 2n\}=1+l_2(n)$, where we denote $l_p(x)=\lfloor\log x/\log p\rfloor$. The case $p\neq 2$ (that we actually need) is a little bit harder:
$$
a_p(n)=\max\left\{2l_p(2n+1)-1,2l_p\left(\frac{2n+1}3\right)\right\}.
$$
(Suppose the maximum in \eqref{expodef} is attained at some $j,k$ and let $\nu_p(2j+1)=m$. Then $2j+1=p^m q$ for some odd integer $q$, and we may assume $q<p$ (otherwise, we can increase $m$, with a possible decrease of $\nu_p(k)$ by at most $1$). If $q=1$ then $\nu_p(k)<m$; the maximum is then attained at $m=l_p(2n+1)$ and $k=p^{m-1}$. Otherwise $q\geqslant 3$ and $\nu_p(k)\leqslant m$; the maximum is attained at $m=l_p\big((2n+1)/3\big)$ and $k=p^m$.)
From this (or otherwise), if $n>4$, we obtain $a_p(n)=1$ for $(2n+1)/3<p\leqslant 2n+1$, and $a_p(n)=2$ for $\sqrt{2n+1}<p\leqslant(2n+1)/3$. Then (for $n>4$), denoting $\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\leqslant x}\log p$, we get
\begin{align}
\log L_n&=\left[\vartheta(2n+1)-\vartheta\left(\frac{2n+1}3\right)\right]
\\&+2\left[\vartheta\left(\frac{2n+1}3\right)-\vartheta(\sqrt{2n+1})\right]
\\&+\underbrace{\sum_{p\leqslant\sqrt{2n+1}}a_p(n)\log p}_{=O(\sqrt{n}\log^2 n)}.
\end{align}
Now $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\log L_n)/n=8/3$ follows from PNT in the form of $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\vartheta(x)/x=1$.

this is a great and beautiful answer !!. I will give you full credits for this proof if I get the goal to $G$ (Catalan´s constant) irrationality... I can focus now to tweak some convergence acceleration methods of Apery-type on rational approximants of $G$ with denominators having this LCM. Many Thanks.
